# Testng get group names without the BeforeMethod

Tags: selenium, testng

I know using this reflection we can surely get list of all groups of the @test.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void befrMethod(Method met){
        Test t = met.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        System.out.println(t.groups()); 
}
```

But Is there a way to get groups list while inside the @test and not beforemethod?
Because I am running tests in parallel and this method is not working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Test method supports ITestContext dependency injection

And this class has a method called

> getIncludedGroups java.lang.String[] getIncludedGroups() Returns: All
> the groups that are included for this test run.

"ITestContext (testng 7.3.0 API)" https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/ITestContext.html

So try

```
@Test
public void befrMethod(ITestContext met){
```